# Want to get a single value from json and add a badge to it using handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

the json data example:

```
data: [
    {name: "brian", product: "computers"},
    {name: "tom", product: "computers"},
    {name: "john", product: "computers"},
    {name: "sara", product: "machines"}
]
```

I want to display a image (badge) next to user that has "machines" as a value for product. How would i do that in handlebars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my own issue but if anybody has a better way of doing it. please add on.

Handlebar helper:

```
  Handlebars.registerHelper('getBadges',function(product){
  var htmlVal = '';
  if(product === "machines") {
    htmlVal = '<span class="machines"><img src="../html/badge_icons/machines-small.png" alt="machines" style="width:30px; height:15px; border:none"></span>';
  } 
  return htmlVal;
});
```

html:

```
{{{getBadges product}}}
```